# Can't upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04.1 to 16.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

After upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, after downloading the packets the installing phase began the window opened the terminal, displayed this:

```
Rozpakowywanie szablonów pakietów dla pakietów: 100%
Prekonfiguracja pakietów...
Rozpakowywanie szablonów pakietów dla pakietów: 100%
Prekonfiguracja pakietów...
Rozpakowywanie szablonów pakietów dla pakietów: 100%
Prekonfiguracja pakietów...
Rozpakowywanie szablonów pakietów dla pakietów: 100%
Prekonfiguracja pakietów...
```

And hanged. Here's the end of /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log

```
2016-11-23 19:21:25,019 ERROR not handled exception:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/yakkety", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 242, in main
if app.run():
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1880, in run
return self.fullUpgrade()
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1845, in fullUpgrade
if not self.doDistUpgrade():
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1183, in doDistUpgrade
res = self.cache.commit(fprogress,iprogress)
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 267, in commit
apt.Cache.commit(self, fprogress, iprogress)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 515, in commit
res = self.install_archives(pm, install_progress)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 479, in install_archives
res = install_progress.run(pm)
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeView.py", line 234, in run
res = os.WEXITSTATUS(self.wait_child())
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewGtk3.py", line 339, in wait_child
self.update_interface()
File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_qub02e8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewGtk3.py", line 346, in update_interface
InstallProgress.update_interface(self)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/progress/base.py", line 255, in update_interface
if float(percent) != self.percent or status_str != self.status:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,0000'
2016-11-23 19:21:25,020 DEBUG running apport_crash()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1633219) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1592817).
I found an inmmediate solution [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2344225), I'm just quoting jml3473's comment (with some adjustments to make it clearer):

> I killed the upgrade python process, then I did:
>   
>   `sudo dpkg --configure -a
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` 
>   The dpkg configure did a number of things but gnome-shell and gnome-session met dependency problems so I did a:
>   `sudo apt-get -f install` 
>   and I'm currently redoing:
>   `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

This did the job for me. I must clarify that I did this immediately after the process got stuck, I read some comments about how after trying to reboot it wouldn't work anymore.